# $r^{th}$ term in the expansion for $\log {(x + \sqrt {x^2+1})}$ using Faa di Bruno formula

Tags: calculus

Recently I came through the following expansion for $\log {(x + \sqrt {x^2+1})}$ :
$$x - \frac {1}{2}.\frac {x^3}{3} + \frac {1}{2}.\frac {3}{4}.\frac {x^5}{5} - ……$$
I think I can use the Faa di Bruno formula to get a closed form for the $r^{th}$ term but I am unable to get good simplifications. If there is some reduction formula or something like that, I welcome any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac{d\ln(x+\sqrt1+x^2)}{dx}=\frac{1+\dfrac x{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}{x+\sqrt1+x^2}=(1+x^2)^{-1/2}$$

Using [Binomial Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) for $|x^2|<1,$

$$(1+x^2)^{-1/2}=1+\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{-1/2(-1/2-1)\cdots(-1/2-(r-1))}{r!}(x^2)^r$$

$$=1+\sum_{r=1}^\infty\dfrac{x^{2r}(-1)^r\prod_{n=1}^r(2n-1)}{r!2^r}$$

Now integrate both sides.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)=\log {(x + \sqrt {x^2+1})}$ is the [inverse hyperbolic sine](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseHyperbolicSine.html) whose expansion is
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (2n-1)!!}{(2n+1)(2n)!!}\, x^{2n+1}$$
where the [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) notation is used (take a look also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Series_expansions)).

This can be obtained by expanding its derivative: 
$$f'(x)=(1+x^2)^{-1/2}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{-1/2}{n}(x^2)^n$$
and then by integrating it.